# Парсинг таймзоны '-030-6'

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

С js-клиента прилетает дата в виде: `1909-09-09T14:27:45.000-030-6`.
Кто-нибудь может предложить паттерн для парсинга таймзоны `-030-6`, или хотя бы пояснить магию этих цифр. Парсить планируется в jodaTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это код зоны с оффсетом времени по гринвичу

```
030 Mexico Standard Time (GMT-06:00)    Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey
```

Это можно парсить с помощью

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZZ");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло